# javascript stopping setinterval with clearinterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

How do you stop setinterval? this is my function but when I click stop it says ReferenceError: goint is not defined

```
<script>
function toggle_interval(x)
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        var i=0;
        var goint = setInterval(function() {
            i++;
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        clearInterval(goint);
    }
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggle_interval(1);">start</a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggle_interval(0);">stop</a>
```

Comment: @ManishMishra No, there's no block scope in JS.

Comment: woah!! let me check, (though that's how it is in half of the world's languages)

Comment: Not in es5, es6 does have that. But there seems to be a lot wrong with this JavaScript code.

Comment: `goint` is scoped to the function. You call the function multiple times. When `x` is 0, `goint` has no value. You need to have `goint` be a global (with the associated problems) or some other mechanism.

Comment: @ManishMishra Not only that, but also look up JS variable hoisting. And variable hoisting when the variable is a function. Welcome to JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable goint is in local scope of your function.

change the scope  of it to global so that it will be available for next call.

```
 var goint;
function toggle_interval(x)
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        var i=0;
        goint = setInterval(function() {
            i++;
            })
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        clearInterval(goint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare goint in global scope that is outside of function toggle_interval.

```
var goint;

function toggle_interval(x)
{
if(x==1)
    {
    var i=0;
    goint    = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        })
    }, 2000);
}else{
    clearInterval(goint);
}
}
```